# Invisible wall problem( Link to blend file in comments)

Tags: mesh, uv, normals

thanks for your time! I know this is most likely a noob problem but it is driving me NUTS , I can't seem to find an answer anywhere. When i create a 3d house model, unwrap it, then export it to unreal as an fbx, most of the walls become invisible...I read somewhere about flipping the normals,i tried that but it still aint working. if ANYONE has a solution i would REALLY appreciate it :) thanks

Comment: could you upload the blend file

Comment: hey dude, thanks for the reply, i dont actually have it anymore :S if it helps, it happens EVERY time i try and build a house. I built a quick house this morning(windows, doors etc) and the same happened when i imported in into unreal engine.

Comment: You should repeat what you've done and replicate the problem and save and upload the blend file. This way someone can help you.

Comment: ahh ok fair enough, will do, ill get a quick simple house done now. when i do it, how do i go about uploading it on here? sorry, im new to this site :P

Comment: ok i have a quick model house, it cud be down to the uv unwrapping as im new to blender.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=3172" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/3172/)

Comment: @Nate Just a tip, that HTML string you just commented is meant to be edited into your original post by choosing _edit_ under your name, and paste it in somewhere. [Here's the official help page for Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help/)